# How use Instruments and display the console in Command Lines applications

Tags: c, xcode, debugging, macos, instruments

I'm using Xcode on OSX to develop command line C applications. I would also like to use Instruments to profile and find memory leaks.

However, I couldn't find a way to display the console when launching the application from within Instruments. I'm also unable to attach to a running command line process (it exits with an error):

Here's an example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

static sigjmp_buf jmpbuf;

void handler(int sig) {
    char c[BUFSIZ];

    printf ("Got signal %d\n", sig);
    printf ("Deseja sair? (s/n) ");

    fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);

    if(c[0] == 's') {
        exit(0);
    } else {
        siglongjmp(jmpbuf, 1);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char buf[BUFSIZ];

    signal(SIGINT, handler);

    sigsetjmp(jmpbuf, 1);

    while(1) {
        printf(">>>");
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
        printf ("Introduziu: %s\n", buf);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Here's the error I got after launching Instruments, and trying to attach to the running process in xcode:

```
[Switching to process 1475]
[Switching to process 1475]
Error while running hook_stop:
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Error while running hook_stop:
Invalid type combination in ordering comparison.
Error while running hook_stop:
Invalid type combination in ordering comparison.
Error while running hook_stop:
Error while running hook_stop:
Error while running hook_stop:
Error while running hook_stop:
Error while running hook_stop:
Error while running hook_stop:
Error while running hook_stop:

Unable to disassemble __CFInitialize.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's easy. See the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 15):

It's a little late to contribute to this old thread, however I have found the best way of profiling a command line utility is to use `iprofiler` ([manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/iprofiler.1.html)).  This allows data to be collected from the command line simply by adding this to the start of the command line:

```
iprofiler -leaks -d $HOME/tmp
```

(I have a private temporary directory at `$HOME/tmp`, so you might need to use `/tmp` or leave the `-d` command line option off altogether).

My test scripts automatically add that to the command line if `$FINDLEAKS` is defined (and will prepend `valgrind` if running under Linux).

This then generates a `.dtps` file (actually a directory) which can be loaded and anaylysed using *Instruments*.

If you are compiling using `clang` then simply add both `-O3` and `-g` (*clang* doesn't support the `-pg` command line option).

Answer (score 3):

You can change the output in the Options dropdown when choosing your target. The output will appear in the system Console (Applications/Utilities/Console).

[image: IO options]

Comment: That doesn't appear to make any difference.

Comment: It does work if you launch instruments from a terminal (run `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/Instruments` on my computer). If you do this and select "System Console" you get the output.

Comment: When I launch it from a terminal, I get nothing — no output at all, and no GUI.